# Basic error in iPad application launch

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a file named MMAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "MMAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MMAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
//and more standard methods
```

MMAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MMAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MainViewController *viewController;

@end
```

MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"view did load main view controller");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

And yet when I run the program, I get a black screen, and the output:

```
2012-02-12 15:44:48.160 MoreMost[44076:f803] view did load main view controller
2012-02-12 15:44:48.163 MoreMost[44076:f803] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to this:

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

And you'll need to create the window, like this:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Comment: You should probably create the `UIWindow` too. That might help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need/want to add the view controller's view as a subview. You want to make your controller the root view controller and iOS will take care of the rest:

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

That is, as of iOS 4. (Not sure the answer if you're going back earlier than that.)

You also need to create the window before you use it. Something like

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
```

Not sure if you aren't or if you just didn't show it ...

Comment: i am synthesizing the window. is this enough? what would be the code to make the window. if i simply change the line to window.rootViewController = viewController, the problem is still there

Comment: Nope. Synthesizing is just create the objective c getter/setter. See my updated answer.